# Name of this lyrical device comparing oneself to something that's described by the same word, but in another sense of the word?

Tags: ambiguity, poetry, comparisons, lyrics

Warning: The examples contain some offensive words, but I believe that is not against the rules here?

Lately I've been listening a lot to a certain hip-hop album, in which almost every track uses a certain lyrical device a lot. Instead of trying to describe it further than I already do in the title, I'll go straight to examples.

​

​

> I've got bars for days, like a custody cell.

[Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-intro-tyen-holding-2-lyrics) The rapper is talking about two different types of bars. First his raps, then the physical bars of a jail cell.

​

> Every fucking album is banging like a Tinder-match

[Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-smooth-operatr-lyrics) He says his albums are "banging" as in musically pleasing, but in the sense of the Tinder-match, the word means sexual intercourse.

​

​

> I jam like a bullet stuck in the barrel

[Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-kan-jeg-fa-et-vitne-lyrics) When he says he jams, he means musically, while the bullet is physically jammed in the barrel.

​

​

> My woman puts on the rubber faster than a pit stop

[Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-jura-lyrics) In the first sense he means a condom, in the second sense he means rubber tyres on a Formula 1 car.

​

​

> I'm harder to hit than a porcupine pussy.

[Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-per-stale-lyrics) In the first sense he means "hit" as in some sort of attack or aggressive action, in the second sense he means sexual intercourse.

​

​

> I stay in the hood like Kenny

[Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-per-stale-lyrics) In his own case, he means his neighbourhood, as in the slang term "hood". In the latter sense he is talking about hood as the part of a jacket that covers the head, referring to the fictional character from South Park who always wears a hood.
​

​

I think that amount of examples (there are countless more from the album, and from other rappers as well) is enough to convey what I mean.

What is the name of this lyrical device? I believe it is somewhat common in Hip Hop, and has been for decades. Does it have a name outside of Hip Hop as well, perhaps in poetry or literature?

Comment: If the singer was "coyly" avoiding being explicitly coarse, it might be described as ***euphemism, innuendo*** or ***double-entendre***.But that doesn't seem to be the case here, so to me it just looks like ***punning***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Generally speaking, ***punning*** is a (very simple) form of "humour", normally done for ***comedic*** effect. I don't really listen to rap much, but my impression is it's ***never*** intended to be "amusing", so I'm not sure that's the best word for your *specific* context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Alright, thanks.

Comment: @RevetahwsaysReinstateMonica Please don't [crosspost](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16656). A question *might* fit on more than site, in which case choose the best fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rhetorical device is called "**zeugma**" ([rhetorical device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_device#Zeugma)).

> Zeugma involves the linking of two or more words or phrases that occupy the same position in a sentence to another word or phrase in the same sentence. This can take advantage of the latter word having multiple meanings depending on context to create a clever use of language that can make the sentence and the claim thus advanced more eloquent and persuasive.
>
> He caught the train and a bad cold.
> This shirt attracts everything but men.
> I held my breath and the door for you.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you are looking for this word— **double entendre**

> a word or expression capable of two interpretations with one usually risqué

*flirty talk full of double entendres*

[Merriam-Webster]